# Attempting to trash item on iOS results in permission denied error - trashItem(at:resultingItemURL:)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIDocument based app where the UIDocuments are packages (in case this is relevant) and I am attempting to send a document to the trash (so they appear under recently deleted) and are recoverable.

The FileManager method, `trashItem(at:resultingItemURL:)` should do this and it was working some time ago - I'm not 100% sure at what stage it stopped working. iOS 13 may have changed something maybe? Now, however, I get an error that reads:

```
[default] [ERROR] can't get operation service for url ~LMD/i{25}e/D{7}s/F{6}1/P{5}n 2.knitchart; 
NSError: Cocoa 257 "The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." }
```

The only recognisable portion of the path is the extension and the preceding 2. The filepath passed to this method is: `file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~com~hazlett~KnitMate/Documents/Folder%201/Pattern%202.knitchart`

The document is viewable, so I'm not sure if the error is referring to the trash folder. Maybe there's a plist flag needed now in iOS 13?

I am working in swift, but if you're more used to it, an objective-c answer is welcome too.